# RMarkdown - function with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, r-markdown, ggplotly

I would like to get a chart in RMarkdown using my function `test1()`. In the function I use `cat()` function and `ggplotly()`, and I picked up that using `cat()` is a main problem in the case. When I remove all codes with `cat()`, I will get what I want ( `test2()` ).
But for me using `cat()` is important because I can create paragraphes and comments in `test1()`. What sould I change in `test1()` and in *test_ggplotly.Rmd* ?

*test_ggplotly.R*

```
library("ggplot2")
library("plotly")

test1<-function(){

  cat('\n')  
  cat("## Chapter 1", "\n") 
  cat("### Example ", "\n") 
  cat(" Comment ", "\n") 
  cat('\n') 

  p1<-ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class)) + geom_point()
  ggplotly(p1)

  cat('\n')   
}


test2<-function(){

  p1<-ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class)) + geom_point()
  ggplotly(p1)
}
```

*test_ggplotly.Rmd*

````
---
title: "Test"
author: " "
date: "10/14/2019"
output: html_document
---
``* {r setup, include=FALSE,echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
``

``{R, echo=FALSE}
source("test_ggplotly.R")
``
``
# Test 1
``{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
test1()
``
# Test 2
``{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
test2()
``
* should be ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to tell R what object to return in the `test1` function :

```
test1<-function(){

        cat('\n')  
        cat("## Chapter 1", "\n") 
        cat("### Example ", "\n") 
        cat(" Comment ", "\n") 
        cat('\n') 

        p1<-ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class)) + geom_point()
        return( ggplotly(p1) )

        cat('\n')
}
```

Comment: But when I change my function test1() it won't work.test1<-function(){
  
  for(i in 1:4)
  cat('\n')  
  cat("## Chapter ", i, "\n") 
  cat("### Exampstle ", "\n") 
  cat(" Comment ", "\n") 
  cat('\n') 
  
  p1<-ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class)) + 
    geom_point() + ggtitle(paste("Chart nr ",i))
  return(ggplotly(p1))

  cat('\n')   
}

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 16/10/19 : #2 For Rmarkdown I use a list as workaround, this may be a specific so question here to find better results.

## 1 the call to `plotly::ggploty()` was indeed forgotten. The code bellow should display the wanted graphs.

Let's reformat your question :

```r
test1<-function(){
        
        library(ggplot2)
        
        for(i in 1:4){
                cat('\n')
                cat("## Chapter ", i, "\n") 
                cat("### Exampstle ", "\n") 
                cat(" Comment ", "\n") 
                cat('\n') 
                
                p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class)) + 
                        geom_point() + 
                        ggtitle(paste("Chart nr ", i))
                
                return(p1)
                
                cat('\n') 
        }
}
test1()
```

If you want only to print the output you can use `print` instead of returning a value :

```r
test1<-function(){
        
        library(ggplot2)

        res <- NULL
        
        for(i in 1:4){
                cat('\n')
                cat("## Chapter ", i, "\n") 
                cat("### Exampstle ", "\n") 
                cat(" Comment ", "\n") 
                cat('\n') 
                
                p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class)) + 
                        geom_point() + 
                        ggtitle(paste("Chart nr ", i))

                p1 <- plotly::ggplotly( p1 )

                res[[i]] <-p1 
        }
        return(res)
}
my_res <- test1()

my_res[[1]]
my_res[[2]]
my_res[[3]]
my_res[[4]]
```

Other wise store each iteration in a list such as `p1[[i]] = ggplot() ...` to call later on.

Comment: One more thing, when using `for()` it is best to add the curly braces `{}` to be sure what is into it. Here it was also an issue I think.

Comment: I had the same solution how above, but unfortunately ggplotly() does't work. ggplotly() is an important thing for me.  Because of that I asked my question.

Comment: `ggplotly()` was missing from the loop.

Comment: Does the code work in RMarkdown? Because in my case I don't have any plots on html document using test_ggplotly.Rmd

Comment: Indeed it does not work with Rmarkdown directly. The only way around I came up with is to not use for loop and call the object directly OR use for loop and store in a list before calling each elements.

Comment: Yes, earlier I had a similar way with assign(), but it wasn't the solution to my expectation.